# Reducing space usage of depth first tree traversal

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection

In Haskell, one can do filters, sums, etc on infinite lists in constant space, because Haskell only produces list nodes when needed, and garbage collects ones it's finished with.

I'd like this to work with infinite trees.

Below is a rather silly program that generates a infinite binary tree with nodes representing the natural numbers.

I've then written a function that does a depth first traversal of this tree, spitting out the nodes at a particular level.

Then I've done a quick sum on the nodes divisable by 5.

In theory, this algorithm could be implemented in `O(n)` space for an `n` depth tree of `O(2^n)` nodes. Just generate the tree on the fly, removing the nodes you've already completed processing.

Haskell does generate the tree on the fly, but doesn't garbage collect the nodes it seems.

Below is the code, I'd like to see code with a similar effect but that doesn't require `O(2^n)` space.

```
import Data.List (foldl')

data Tree = Tree Int Tree Tree

tree n = Tree n (tree (2 * n)) (tree (2 * n + 1))
treeOne = tree 1

depthNTree n x = go n x id [] where
  go :: Int -> Tree -> ([Int] -> [Int]) -> [Int] -> [Int]
  go 0 (Tree x _ _) acc rest = acc (x:rest)
  go n (Tree _ left right) acc rest = t2 rest where 
    t1 = go (n - 1) left acc
    t2 = go (n - 1) right t1

main = do
  x <- getLine
  print . foldl' (+) 0 . filter (\x -> x `rem` 5 == 0) $ depthNTree (read x) treeOne
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `depthNTree` uses `2^n` space because you keep the left subtree around through `t1` while you're traversing the right subtree. The recursive call on the right subtree should contain no reference to the left, as a necessary condition for incrementally garbage collected traversals.

The naive version works acceptably in this example:

```
depthNTree n t = go n t where
  go 0 (Tree x _ _) = [x]
  go n (Tree _ l r) = go (n - 1) l ++ go (n - 1) r
```

Now `main` with input 24 uses 2 MB space, while the original version used 1820 MB. The optimal solution here is similar as above, except it uses difference lists:

```
depthNTree n t = go n t [] where
  go 0 (Tree x _ _) = (x:)
  go n (Tree _ l r) = go (n - 1) l . go (n - 1) r
```

This isn't much faster than the plain list version in many cases, because with tree-depths around 20-30 the left nesting of `++` isn't very costly. The difference becomes more pronounced if we use large tree depths:

```
print $ sum $ take 10 $ depthNTree 1000000 treeOne
```

On my computer, this runs in 0.25 secs with difference lists and 1.6 secs with lists.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. I've also asked a follow up question on how the garbage collector actually achieves what you have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433757/how-the-haskell-garbage-collector-works

Comment: I fielded some questions about this answer in IRC today, and I think one part of it is a bit misleading. The problem with the original code isn't that an accumulator exists at all, it's that the accumulator works from back-to-front, which is the inherently non-productive part. I think this clarification is worthwhile to make.

Comment: @Carl I don't think accumulated results can ever be productive. Maybe we use the terminology differently. Even if we mix accumulators with guarded recursion (e. g. as in `enumFrom`), productivity comes solely from guardedness, never from accumulation.

Comment: I had to take a while to think it through thoroughly. But I'm sure my analysis is reasonable now. Your last version uses an accumulator. Eta-expand the definition of `go`and you'll see where it was hiding. We could argue about the definition of "accumulator" a bit, especially in the context of non-strict evaluation, but that last argument would definitely be an accumulator in a strict language. I think it remains one in a non-strict language. I accept that my definition isn't ever going to be universal, but I think it has merit.

Comment: @Carl yeah, I think now that my word choice does not precisely address the OP. Edited.