# How the Haskell garbage collector efficiently collects trees

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection

This code from the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430622/reducing-space-usage-of-depth-first-tree-traversal/34432102#34432102) copied below quite nicely takes only `O(n)` space to do a depth first traversal of a tree of depth `n` which contains `O(2^n)` nodes. This is very good, the garbage collector seems to be doing a good job of cleaning up the already processed tree.

But my question I have is, how? Unlike a list, where once we process the first element we can completely forget it, we can't scrap the root node after processing the first leaf node. We have to wait until the left half the tree is processed (because eventually we'll have to traverse down the right from the root). Also, as the root node points to the nodes below it, and so on, all the way down to the leaves, which would seem to imply that we wouldn't be able to collect any of the first half of a tree until we start on the second half (as all those nodes will still have references to them starting from the still live root node). This fortunately is not the case, but could someone explain how?

```
import Data.List (foldl')

data Tree = Tree Int Tree Tree

tree n = Tree n (tree (2 * n)) (tree (2 * n + 1))
treeOne = tree 1

depthNTree n t = go n t [] where
  go 0 (Tree x _ _) = (x:)
  go n (Tree _ l r) = go (n - 1) l . go (n - 1) r

main = do
  x <- getLine
  print . foldl' (+) 0 . filter (\x -> x `rem` 5 == 0) $ depthNTree (read x) treeOne
```

Comment: Couldn't it be that it only stores the O(n) nodes it is currently checking? I.e. if it processed a leaf, it forgets it and replaces it by the next leaf.

Also, Haskell is known for it's laziness, meaning that it will not evaluate anything it does not currently need.

Comment: *"We have to wait until the left half the tree is processed"*. Use that argument recursively, and you'll notice a pattern.

Comment: I somehow assumed that having a top-level binding like `treeOne` above would prevent any garbage collection. Maybe GHC is optimizing more than I thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a little manual evaluation of a tree to depth 2. I hope it can illustrate why tree nodes can be garbage collected along the way.

Suppose we start with a tree like this:

```
tree =
  Tree
    (Tree _          -- l
       (Tree a _ _)    -- ll
       (Tree b _ _))   -- lr
    (Tree _          -- r
       (Tree c _ _)    -- rl
       (Tree d _ _))   -- rr
```

Now call `depthNTree 2 tree`:

```
go 2 tree []
go 2 (Tree _ l r) []            
go 1 l (go 1 r [])
go 1 (Tree _ ll lr) (go 1 r [])
go 0 ll (go 0 lr (go 1 r []))
go 0 (Tree a _ _) (go 0 lr (go 1 r []))
a : go 0 lr (go 1 r [])                   -- gc can collect ll
a : go 0 (Tree b _ _) (go 1 r [])
a : b : go 1 r []                         -- gc can collect lr and thus l
a : b : go 1 (Tree _ rl rr) []
a : b : go 0 rl (go 0 rr [])
a : b : go 0 (Tree c _ _) (go 0 rr [])
a : b : c : go 0 rr []                    -- gc can collect rl
a : b : c : go 0 (Tree d _ _) []
a : b : c : d : []                        -- gc can collect rr and thus r and tree
```

Note that since `treeOne` is a static value, there has to be some extra machinery behind the scenes to allow garbage collection of it. Fortunately GHC [supports GC](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/GC/CAFs) of static values.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you don't hold on to the root while you descend the left subtree.

```
go n (Tree _ l r) = go (n - 1) l . go (n - 1) r
```

So the root is turned two thunks, composed together. One holds a reference to the left subtree, the other holds a reference to the right subtree. The root node itself is now garbage.

The left and right subtrees themselves *are just thunks*, because the tree is produces lazily, so they aren't consuming much space yet.

We're only evaluating `go n (Tree _ l r)` because we're evaluating `depthNTree n t`, which is `go n t []`. So we're immediately forcing the two composed `go` calls we just turned the root into:

```
(go (n - 1) l . go (n - 1) r) []
= (go (n - 1) l) ((go (n - 1) r) [])
```

And because this is lazily evaluated, we do the *outermost* call first, leaving `((go (n - 1) r) [])` as a thunk (and so not generating any more of `r`).

Recursing into `go` will force `l`, so we do generate more of that. But then we do the same thing again one level down; again that tree node becomes garbage immediately, we generate two thunks holding the left and right sub sub trees, and then we force only the left one.

After `n` calls we'll be evaluating `go 0 (Tree x _ _) = (x:)`. We've generated `n` pairs of thunks, and forced the `n` left ones, leaving the right ones in memory; because the right sub-trees are unevaluated thunks they're constant space each, and there are only `n` of them, so only `O(n)` space total. And all the tree nodes leading to this path are now unreferenced.

We actually have the outermost list constructor (and the first element of the list). Forcing more of the list will explore those right sub-tree thunks further down the composition chain being built up, but there will never be more than `n` of them.

---

Technically you have bound a reference to `tree 1` in the globally scoped `treeOne`, so actually you could retain a reference to every node you ever produce, so you're relying on GHC noticing that `treeOne` is only ever used once and shouldn't be retained.

Comment: This is also a very good answer but I can only accept one. All three were great thank you and they've all got an upvote (and deserve more)..

Answer (score 3):

Let's rewrite the recursive case of `go` as

```
go n t = case t of
           Tree _ l r -> go (n - 1) l . go (n - 1) r
```

In the right-hand side of the case alternative, the original tree `t` is no longer live. Only `l` and `r` are live. So, if we recurse into `l` first, say, there is nothing keeping the left-hand side of the tree live except `l` itself; `r` exactly keeps the right-hand side of the tree alive.

At any point in the recursion, the live nodes are exactly the roots of the subtrees cut off by the path from the original root of the tree to the node currently being inspected which have not already been processed. There are at most the length of said path of these subtrees, so the space usage is O(n).

The key is that the original tree `t` becomes dead before we recurse. If you write the (denotationally equivalent, but bad style for a number of reasons)

```
leftChild (Tree _ l r) = l
rightChild (Tree _ l r) = r

go n t = go (n - 1) (leftChild t) . go (n - 1) (rightChild t)
```

now when recursing into `go (n - 1) (leftChild t)`, there is still a live reference to `t` in the unevaluated expression `rightChild t`. Hence the space usage is now exponential.

Comment: This is also a very good answer but I can only accept one. All three were great thank you and they've all got an upvote (and deserve more)..